# Function to shuffle contents of String array in java

Tags: java, android

Is there any built in function to shuffle contents of String array in java/android?

For example,
To shuffle array a.

```
a[4]={"abc","cde","def","ghi"}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `Collections.shuffle()` in java to shuffle the elements inside the array

```
Collections.shuffle( a);
for (String i : a) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```